# Create Array from other Arrays in an Object

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an object that contains 3 arrays from which I need to create a new array.

This is what I have currently

```
function getItems(items)
{
    var returnArray = [];

    for(var i = 0; i < items.length; i++)
    {
        var item = items[i];   

        returnArray.push({ 
            id: item.product_sku,
            quantity: Math.round(item.product_quantity),
            price: item.product_price 
        });
    }

    return returnArray;
}

my_data = { product_price: "82.990000000, 26.750000000, 19.250000000", product_quantity: "1.000000000, 2.000000000, 1.000000000", product_sku: "1207, 1212, 1309" }


var viewBasket = JSON.stringify(getItems(my_data));

console.log("viewBasket = " + viewBasket);
```

This is what I'm expecting/hoping to see:

```
viewBasket  =  [ 
     { id: "1207", price: "82.990000000", quantity: "1.0" },
     { id: "1212", price: "26.750000000", quantity: "2.0" }, 
     { id: "1309", price: "19.250000000", quantity: "1.0" }
 ];
```

But it returns "viewBasket = []";

Comment: `for(var i = 0; i < items.length; i++)` but `items` is an object, not an array - it doesn't have a `length` property. What are you trying to iterate? [Properties?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8312459/iterate-through-object-properties)

Comment: Sounds like that could be the problem right there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take an array with the wanted source and target keys and iterate the keys and map the values.

```js
var data = { checkout_pagename_url: "/checkout", order_total: "148.240000000", product_id: "126256, 126339, 131822", product_list_price: "82.990000000, 26.750000000, 19.250000000", product_discount: "0, 0, 0", product_name: "NorthShore AirSupreme Tab-Style Briefs, Medium, Case/60 (4/15s), NorthShore AirSupreme Tab-Style Briefs, Large, Pack/15, NorthShore FlexSupreme Pull-On Underwear, Large, Pack/14", product_quantity: "1.000000000, 2.000000000, 1.000000000", product_sku: "1207, 1212, 1309", product_price: "82.990000000, 26.750000000, 19.250000000", order_coupon_code: "" },
    keys = [['product_sku', 'id'], ['product_price', 'price'], ['product_quantity', 'quantity']],
    viewBasket = keys.reduce((r, [source, target]) => data[source]
        .split(', ')
        .map((v, i) => Object.assign(r[i] || {}, { [target]: v })) , []);

console.log(viewBasket);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

`items` is an object, not an array. You have to turn the strings into arrays first:

```
  const 
     prices = viewBasket.product_price.split(", "),
     quantities = viewBasket.product_quantity.split(", "),
     skus = viewBasket.product_sku.split(", ");
```

Then you can iterate over one of those by index, and access the values at the index of each of the arrays and build up objects from that.